Как можно реализовать поиск не цифровых символов в строке?(кроме '.' , ',')
Допустим имеем код аля
char str[];
int s = 0;
printf("Enter symbol set");
fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
while(str[s] != '\0'){

    if(str[s] == "Описание не цировых символовов"){
        printf("Not a number in the term");
    }
    ++s;

}

Вопрос в том как именно можно находить не цифры в строке, совсем не могу найтик как это сделать и сам додуматься тоже(

Я бы не мудрствовал лукаво :) со всякими там isdigit (да еще и e разрешено, например, или +-), а взял функцию strtof и смотрел, принимает ли она всю строку или нет... Кстати, неужели у вас char str[]; компилируется?

да, компилируется)

ну тут не весь код, я просто накидал на скорую руку часть своего, чтобы было понятно в общих чертах

Вот так, без указания размера и без инициализатора? 8-\ А что у вас за компилятор?

Visual studio 2022, у себя я размер указал 12, тут просто решил упустить, за это извиняюсь, а так да, без инициализатора

можете примерно подсказать  как тут со strtof получить информацию о непринятии и использовать ее?

Какая задача? Прочитать double из строки во входном потоке?

ну, смотрите, задача впринципе в том чтобы если в строке были не цифры то она выдавала ошибку, а хочу я это использовать в своем коде где я ввожу цифры в строку и строка конвертируются в double через atof()

весь остальной код у меня уже написан и работает но для подстраховки хочу чтобы выдавало конкретную ошибка что есть не цифры

12.34 - это правильный ввод? -12.34? 1e10?

12.34 да, -12.34 нет, потому что у меня стоит проверка на отрицательность, 1е10 да, потому что у е есть значение, а вот что-то по типу 11b3 или 11.f4 должно выдавать ошибку

Вы тогда заголовок вопроса перепишите. e, ., - не очень то цифровые. Погуляю с собаками, вернусь и помогу. Вы пока сюда поглядите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1594377

Да, уже глянул, но я к тому времени уже сделал по-своему через счетчик точек и работает четко, я как раз для того кода хочу интегрировать проверку на наличие не цифровых, думал через-то по типу else if (!isdigit(stra[a]) && stra[a] != ',' && stra[a] != '.'){printf("Error, invalid character '%c' in input. Only digits are allowed.\n")}

Тогда вы всё что я могу предложить видели. Считать точки и проверять символы я не стал.

@Егор, то, что минус в показателе степени (например -- число 1e-10) вам по условию подходит, в своих проверках учли?

вот как раз с этим e и -e не могу разобраться как реализовать(, извините что пропал на такое долгое время, в учебу погрузился

Решаем задачу "как забить гвоздь", а не "какой рукой держать микроскоп при забивании гвоздя"...
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double getPositiveDouble(const char * s, int*error)
{
    char * end;
    double x = strtod(s,&end);
    if (error)
    {
        *error = (*end || x == HUGE_VAL || x < 0);
        // Или иная (например, с помещением кода ошибки
        // в error) обработка ошибки. Если нужна :)
    }
    return x;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    const char * s[] = { "123.456"," 345.3e2", "121rf", "1234.88 ", "-125" };
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]); ++i)
    {
        int error;
        double x;
        x = getPositiveDouble(s[i],&error);
        printf("s = [%s], x = %lf, error = %d\n",s[i],x,error);
    }
}

Просто убеждаемся, что все символы преобразованы. Не должно быть ничего лишнего, даже обычного пробела, после завершения числа.

Я бы разрешил пробелы перед и после числа.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Перед - и так strtod допускает, после - ну, там несложно дописать соответствующую проверку, думаю, ТС справится — если сочтет это нужным, само собой...

Для отрицательного числа error должен бы указывать на - ...

@avp Тоже - как ТС пожелает, так и сделает :)

А он догадается возвращать в *error индекс символа следующего за ошибочным (а если ошибки нет, то 0)?

@avp Дописал комментарий, пусть догадывается :)

Есть две школы: value = f(&error) и error = f(&value). Я себя отношу ко второй. Какие есть мотивы для первой записи?

@StanislavVolodarskiy Если есть основания ошибку вообще игнорировать...
